# If M and N are nonzero, finitely generated R-modules with M projective, then $M\otimes N$ is nonzero

Tags: tensor-products, projective-module

I am trying to work through the following problem:

If M and N are nonzero, finitely generated R-modules with M projective, then $M\otimes N$ is nonzero.

My thought on how to approach this problem is to suppose $M\otimes N=0$ and to use the universal property of the tensor product.  Any biadditive map from $M\times N$ must then be the zero map by commutativity of the appropriate diagram.

I am unsure of what group I should map $M\times N$ biadditively to.  Also I don't see where projectivity and finitely generated will come into play using this approach.

Perhaps there is a better way to approach the problem.  Any hints pertaining to my approach or better ways to do the problem are welcome.

Comment: What if $R=R_1 \times R_2$ and $M$ is nonzero on $\mathrm{spec}(R_1)$ and zero on $\mathrm{spec}(R_2)$ and $N$ the other way round? Maybe some hypotheses on $R$ are needed too.

Comment: The only hypothesis I have on R is that R has identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jürgen's comment is right on the money: if $R = R_1 \times R_2$ then you can take $M = R_1, N = R_2$. These are both finitely generated and projective, but $M \otimes N = 0$.

You need an extra condition on either $M$ or $R$. I think a sufficient condition on $R$ is that it has no nontrivial idempotents, and a sufficient condition on $M$ is that it has full support in the sense that all of its localizations $M_p$ are nonzero.

Comment: Thank you.  This is a qualifying exam question, so I didn't even think to check for counterexamples; I assumed the question was correct.

Comment: I've found that it's useful to build a habit of alternating trying to prove things and trying to find counterexamples to them. No need to commit yourself to believing one thing or the other in advance, and sometimes what you learn in one can be directly helpful in doing the other.